# Obtaining the string value from separate window to be used on another. Objective C

Tags: objective-c, message-passing, nstextfieldcell

I have a window with a large NSTextFeildCell, where text can be modified. Upon clicking a button another window appears where the text from the original window can be used some how. The issue I am having is when I attempt to retrieve that text the log spits out...

" -[NSTextView stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100151860"
Fallowed by a long trace...

I have tried to solve this several different ways but with no luck.

currently,

First window controller

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class NextWindowController;
@interface TextViewWindowController : NSWindowController
@property (nonatomic, weak) NextWindowController *NextWindow;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSTextFieldCell *txtTextView;

- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender;
- (NSString*)getText;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "TextViewWindowController.h"
#import "NextWindowController.h"
@implementation TextViewWindowController
@synthesize NextWindow;
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender{
   [NextWindow setCallingWindow:self];
   [NextWindow showWindow:self];
}
- (NSString*)getText{
   return [_txtTextView stringValue];// there is a problem with the view...
}
@end
```

Next Window controller

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class TextViewWindowController;
@interface NextWindowController : NSWindowController{
   NSMutableString* str;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) TextViewWindowController *callingWindow;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "NextWindowController.h"
#import "TextViewWindowController.h"
@implementation NextWindowController
@synthesize callingWindow;
- (IBAction)btnEnterClicked:(id)sender{
   [str setString:callingWindow.txtTextView.stringValue];
}

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
       str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I have also tried str = [callingWindow getText] with the same result.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not super intuitive to figure out from Apple's documentation, but to get the raw string value of a NSTextView ([which inherits from NSText](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/string)), just use:

```
[_txtTextView string];
```

And since you're using properties, it might be smarter to use the accessor in your function, like this:

```
- (NSString*)getText{
   return [self.txtTextView string];
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a method called `getText`, that sort of implies that values are being returned by reference in the method's parameters.

Comment: Fantastic point.  Hopefully Daniel can change the name from "`getText`" or... even better... simply access the property from the *other* view controller (e.g. "`[callingWindow.txtTextView string];`")

Comment: Agreed. A virtual +1 until the clock ticks over :)

Comment: Yes, Thank you guys. I was originally had it set up that way. I was hoping however that if i had created that method, id be abile to trace through better... no such luck. But this makes more sense. I'll comment back if I run into another bug. Thanks again!